# Xpath-filtering items

Tags: xpath, filtering

I have a short question. How can I display only the elements who's value is = '.'

I have no idea how to do that. I'm newbie in XPath.

```
 <SalesTransaction>
  <TransactionHeader>
   <TransactionHeaderFields>
  <WrntyID>a</WrntyID>
  <ExternalID/>
  <Type>.</Type>
  <Status>
    Submited
  </Status>
  <CreationDate>
    2015-01-12
  </CreationDate>
  <Date>
    2015-01-12T11:41:29Z
  </Date>
  <DeliveryDate>
    2015-01-12
  </DeliveryDate>
  <Remark/>
</TransactionHeaderFields>
<CatalogFields>
  <CatalogID>
   saf
  </CatalogID>
</CatalogFields>
 </TransactionHeader>
     </SalesTransaction>
```

Comment: how about /SalesTransaction/TransactionHeader/Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring any of the structure and just looking for any element who's `text()` is equal to ".", you could use:

```
//*[text()='.']
```

- `//*` will search through the entire tree structure, looking for any element at any level
- `[text()='.']` is a predicate filter (kind of like a WHERE clause in SQL) that performs a test on each of those matched elements. Only the ones that have a `text()` node who's value is equal to `.` will evaluate to `true()` and will be what is left.

It's not not he most efficient XPath expression, but may be good enough for what you need.